# What is the most common term for American football in Korean?

Tags: word-choice

During a conversation with ChatGPT about American football, the tool warned me that the term [미식축구](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%AF%B8%EC%8B%9D%EC%B6%95%EA%B5%AC)(美式蹴球) is not widely understood, and that I should prefer the word 아메리칸 풋볼, which could be more easily understood. However, I get much less web results for my search with 아메리칸 풋볼 compared with 미식축구. Also, both terms could be found in my YBM ENG-KOR dictionary.

PS: I know ChatGPT can be imprecise at times, so that´s why I am asking for human help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

American football itself is not commonly mentioned in Korea. However, the term '미식축구' is more preferred than '아메리칸 풋볼'.

Although number of search results in Google is not a precise metric for how widely the term is used, it is a convenient and easy number to compare. The term '미식축구' yields 3,920,000 results, while '아메리칸 풋볼' yields 237,000 results in Google search. Note that most of the results in the latter redirects to the term '미식축구'.